# Best GWT CodeSplitting design to encapsulate "modules"

Tags: java, gwt

I am currently faced with quite a challenging issue related to GWT codesplitting and was hoping for some help.

I currently work on a large legacy GWT application (pre-MVP days) and I am looking to code split this application based on the modules that the "portlets" (what we call the various composite widgets that we build our pages up with) are part of.

Currently our modules are just identified by the package that the portlet falls into but I am open to changing this to better suit a sound generic codesplitting design.

Any ideas on how I can design this code to indicate that a portlet / composite belongs to a specific "module" and then split the code so that the first time any portlet / composite within module X is loaded, the whole of module X is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Still having problems? +1 for motivation :)

Comment: haha have had no time to look into it since you left @Nico but it is coming up soon so thought I would ask the question so long :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... normally, it's quite simple but I guess that's not your real problem ...

Simply use this:

```
GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
    public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
        ...
    }
    public void onSuccess() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Everything within the onSuccess method will then be splitted in another javascript file which will then be loaded on demand.

In case you want to seperate composites from the rest of your code, simply put the creation of your composite inside this onSuccess method.

You also can nest GWT.runAsync methods, so you can split the part again in different parts, e.g. first GWT.runAsync loads module X, in constructor of module X you could do another runAsync which then loads your composize.

Of couse, there could be some dependencies between the part which make it difficult for the compiler to split but I have tested it with one of my projects (about 40k lines of code) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: thanks for the response but I do know how to use code splitting, I was looking more for a design pattern to use for splitting out entire modules without adding the async callback for every composite (basically a variation on the patterns that the GWT team have published)

Answer (score 0):

Packagaing has little to do with code splitting, the main factor that makes code splitting work is little spaghetti entanglement between classes. If one class requires another and so on which eventually reaches and grabs all classes then code splitting cant very well break things up into many, because the very act of requiring the first means everything is required. If you separate your concerns aka loose coupling then you should be able to have something that is well suited to being splittable.

Comment: thanks for the response but I am already aware of everything that you have mentioned. As I said in my question, currently our modules are split purely by package but I am open to changing that (since I know it has nothing to do with codesplitting). What I am asking for is a way to group multiple composites into a client-side "module" and get some sort of "manager" class that is smart enough to load an entire module when any composite from that module is used. I want to avoid writing these async callbacks for each and every composite.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) - it's a good MVP framework and they provide you with automatic code splitting. You would have to reorganize your code base to use a presenter/view for each of the modules that you want to split. Then adding codesplitting is as simple as adding the following lines to your presenter:

```
@ProxyCodeSplit
@NameToken("firstpage")
public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<FirstPagePresenter> {}
```

GWTP also has an Eclipse plugin that generates most of the boilerplate code.

Comment: I wish we could do that, unfortunately our system is quite "long in the tooth" and is quite heavily tied in to an open-source framework that one of our ex-architects wrote called gwt-portlets. It is a massive system that would take more time than we have at the moment to refactor into an MVP-type design. I will have a look into this though and if it turns out to be feasible for us then I will accept your answer.

Comment: You don't have to refactor all your code base to MVP, just your top level containers. Say your app is split in five different sections, you would have a top level presenter/view containing the 5 sections each refactored as a presenter/view. Each section could still contain gwt portlets, you don't have to refactor the portlets as well to benefit from code splitting.

Comment: mmmm.... that could work for us, I'll put some time into doing a proof of concept based on that design and if it works out I'll accept your answer. Thanks very much for the suggestion.